Is there a way publish my GitHub workflow as a starter workflow?
I have created a workflow to generate sphinx docs using (sphinx_example_includer). Is there a way to publish a workflow in GitHub so it can be imported (without copy pasting the workflow).
So either by making it show as one of GitHub's starter workflows (screenshot attached)
or by offering a link so it redirects the user to some page on GitHub where they can import it.
I looked at the GitHub docs, but I did not find it.

You could make a reusable workflow, but there's no built-in way for people to automatically add it into their own repos.

So do, the action can be published in GitHub Marketplace. Here is the official guide.
Here are the steps I followed:

Create a repo with action.yml.
Write the README.md file (to describe your project for users).
A message will be shown "Publish this Action to the GitHub Marketplace".
Create a release (note the release version will be used by others).
If everything is good, you will have your action in the Marketplace. I have mine here.

